# Can any Pokemon learn False Swipe, Mean Look, and a move to inflict paralysis or sleep?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

I am going after the roaming pokemon in Pokemon SoulSilver, and they are a nuisance to catch. I need Mean Look to ensure that they don't immediately run, False Swipe to hurt it as much as possible without fainting it, and a move to paralyze them or put them to sleep to catch them.

At the moment, this means using three Pokemon, which is a nuisance as it wastes time switching between them. Are there any Pokemon that can learn this combination of moves?

Comment: Note that moves like Spider Web and Mean Look lose their effect if you switch out. You have to Baton Pass it out if you want to keep its effect.

Comment: Always remember that one Pokemon can learn any move easily, and that is Smeargle. Just get the other Pokemon with the move you need, get into a double battle, use it, sketch it, level Smeargle up to the next tenth level or go to a move tutor, repeat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 2 Pokémon that can learn that combination of moves via TM and breeding.

**Absol** can get Mean Look as an Egg Move from Umbreon, can learn False Swipe from TM, and can learn Thunder Wave from a TM.

**Gallade** can learn Mean Look as an Egg Move from most ghosts, learns False Swipe naturally at level 45, and can opt for either Thunder Wave as a TM or Hypnosis as a level 50 Kirlia (this route would require you to use either the Move Tutor or a TM for False Swipe, but Sleep is better for catching).

Comment: Aw, your answer's better... :p

Answer (score 7):

If you want to look up moveset combinations, check out Serebii's [Moveset Calculator](http://www.serebii.net/games/moveset.shtml). For the moves you want, Absol, Gallade and Smeargle will work.

Personally, if you want something effective, I used to have a Smeargle with the following moveset:

- Spore (100% chance of sleep)
- Mean Look
- False Swipe

With the fourth slot being anything of your choice. I can't remember what I had. I think it was Odor Sleuth in case I needed to catch a Ghost-type.

Answer (score 4):

I did a quick search with [this](http://www.legendarypokemon.net/dp_moveset.html), and found that [Absol](http://www.legendarypokemon.net/dp/pokedex/Absol) and [Gallade](http://www.legendarypokemon.net/dp/pokedex/Gallade) are the only two Pokemon beside [Smeargle](http://www.legendarypokemon.net/dp/pokedex/Smeargle) that learn both of those. They can both be taught Thunder Wave from a TM.

EDIT: Also, Gallade can know Hypnosis if Kirlia knows it when it evolves.

Answer (score 2):

I wish to improve upon Corey's answer. It is a decent answer, but I must point something out.
If you want to catch Entei/Raiku, Mean Look, and Spore is a must. BUT If you do not use Spore IMMEDIATELY after using mean look, they WILL use roar. Forcing your pokemon to run, ending the battle. So having a Smeargle with Taunt in the 4th moveslot is equally as helpful, if you don't have access to spore. But it is just as temporary as Spore, (2- 5 turns), so you need to have something that can attack hard, and fast. Assuming your Smeargle is at least Lv.50, but I'd recommend at least level 65, due to it's appalling terrible stats. (The Lengendary dogs at LV.40) That way the attack stat of Smeargle is good enough to cut it's HP down to 1 with False Swipe. I recommend using either Silk Scarf, or Metronome as a held item (to power up False Swipe). For where they can be acquired, see your games walk through.

Answer (score 0):

Absol can learn False Swipe from TM, and you can breed a FEMALE Absol with a MALE watchog (the watchog must have mean look) then you put them in the daycare and you will get an egg with an Absol that knows mean look, and if the parent Absol has false swipe, then it will already know Mean look and False swipe. Hope that helped!

Answer (score -1):

Get a Smeargle and use Sketch (when you do it with a friend battle this more easy), Sketch lets you learn the last used move from your foe and keep it permanently.

Comment: How is this any different than the other 3 answers?