# Search for Pokemon by moves learned

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I'm looking for a website that lets you filter Pokemon by moves. So, say I'm looking for a Pokemon with the move combination False Swipe, Spore, and Leech Seed. I would enter those moves and get a list of Pokemon that can learn them as results. Is there such a tool/website or do I need to go create one?

I'm looking for one that covers all generations or at the very least the current generation.

Comment: The only tool I know of is [Serebii's Moveset Calculator](http://www.serebii.net/games/moveset.shtml), but it only contains Pokémon up until Gen IV, so I'm not posting this as an answer.

Comment: @Kevin: For reference, that is basically what I'm looking for though. If only we had a 5th generation one.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure Serebii will update it at some point.

Comment: I can't search it at work, @KevinY or Rapida, but might legendarypokemon.net have one for Black/White? [From this question on D/P movesets](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/can-any-pokemon-learn-false-swipe-mean-look-and-a-move-to-inflict-paralysis-or), one of the answers suggests that site for a moveset searcher, it may have one.

Comment: @GraceNote: It looks like they only have 3rd and 4th generation at the moment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Veekun](http://veekun.com/) has an excellent [advanced search form](http://veekun.com/dex/pokemon/search), which includes exactly this, with data from all generations.

Comment: Forgot about Veekun's amazing search engine; great answer.

Answer (score 4):

I started working on a tool for my site a little while back when I couldn't find anything for gen 5. This question prompted me to [finish a beta version here](http://pokemondb.net/tools/moveset-search).

Still got a few things to add, like egg moves for evolved forms. For example, searching Mean Look and Hypnosis shows Zubat but not Golbat/Crobat who obviously can also learn them, nor Gallade who only learns Hypnosis in a pre-evolved state. (Veekun has the same issue, by the way.)

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of finishing what I posted in my comment, Serebii just updated their [moveset calculator](http://www.serebii.net/games/moveset-bw.shtml) to work with Black and White.